# Changing a particular value in a particular line (say line number:57) and saving the file with same file name using python

Tags: python

```
import fileinput
import sys
def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    i=1
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):        
        if i==57:
            if searchExp in line:
                line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
            sys.stdout.write(line)
        i+=1
replaceAll("5MW_Platform_karbarge.DAT","22.0","23.0")
```

This code is running, problem is the rest of lines in the file are missing after execution. Could anyone please suggest modifications so that except line 57, the rest of file is undisturbed? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you only write line 57 back to the file just move sys.stdout.write out of the `if i==57` so every line writen, but only 57 is replaced.

This should work

```
import fileinput
import sys
def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    i=1
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):        
        if i==57:
            if searchExp in line:
                line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        i+=1
replaceAll("5MW_Platform_karbarge.DAT","22.0","23.0")
```

Comment: hi bruno. you're awesome. Thanks.